# Customize the addition/subtraction symbols in git diff?

Tags: git, diff

When you run `$ git diff`, the default for the output is to show deletions with a minus symbol and additions with a plus symbol. Is there a way to customize these symbols to an arbitrary symbol in the git command itself? (instead of having to set up a separate config file.)

For example, if I run `$ git diff --word-diff`, deleted text would show up as:

```
[-this text has been deleted -]
```

And added text would show up as:

```
{+this text has been added+}
```

I'm hoping to be able to specify in the git diff command that deletions should be marked with, say `[-##`, and additions marked with, say `{+##`.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

`--output-indicator-xxx` option is what you are looking for. See [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

From the docs:

> ```
> --output-indicator-new=<char>
> --output-indicator-old=<char>
> --output-indicator-context=<char>
> ```
>
> Specify the character used to indicate new, old or context lines in
> the generated patch. Normally they are `+`, `-` and ' ' respectively.

EDIT: Apparently, when `--word-diff is used`, the above option is not available. A more general workaround would be piping a call to `sed`.

For instance, I'll make one example, there are plenty of questions about [sed](/questions/tagged/sed): `git diff ... | sed -e s/\[-/[-##/` will substitute any `[-` with `[-##`. Same caveat as the original command: if that string is part of the diff output, that'll be affected (e.g. `[-some code removed [--hi--]-]` will become `[-##some code removed [-##-hi--]-]`.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work for the use case I noted. (i) Based on my testing at least: 'output-indicator' does work with --word-diff. When I try a --word-diff, using output indicator doesn't change the symbols. (ii) output-indicator gives an error if you use more than one character (if you try to change the + to +##, for example). Happy to find out if I am missing something.

Comment: Looks like you are right. I assumed it should have worked. Would you be interested in a non-git native answer? If so, I'd pipe a gawk/sed call to replace the chars. Looks like the options you are using comes with pre-made char delimiters.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure gawk/sed could work, but I'm also not familiar with those methods. Would you be able to provide an example that I could test out?

Comment: @9gt53wS I made an example edit, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the sed command. I don't think it works for my purposes. I need something that stays within git, and also that directly addresses only the symbols that git adds ("{+", "[-", etc), not symbols in the underlying text.

Comment: well, try getting the attention of someone in the mainteneance chain to implement this. I'd point out that my initial thought works just like I described. There is no content escape, apparently, so ambiguity is not handled in the end.